# Django with WSGI behind Apache VirtualHost gives 404

Tags: django, apache, python-2.7, virtualhost

I'm trying to run a Django application on an Apache server, in a virtual host using WSGI.

I followed the Django docs exactly, but it there still seems to be some issue here.

I have everything configured properly as far as I can tell.

wsgi.py:

```
import os
import sys

path='/var/www/docs/'
sys.path.append(path)

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "DocsEngine.settings"

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

virtualhost file:

```
Listen 8000

WSGIPythonPath /var/www/docs

<VirtualHost *:8000>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/docs/DocsEngine/wsgi.py

    ServerName myurl.com
    Alias /resources/ /var/www/docs/resources/

    <Directory /var/www/docs/DocsEngine>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files> 
    </Directory>

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/wsgi-access.log combined  
    ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/wsgi-error.log

</VirtualHost>
```

When navigating to `myurl.com:8000/` it comes up with a 404 page.

- My firewall has port 8000 open
- This vhost is enabled in apache.
- Apache has mod_wsgi enabled
- The django app works when running it locally with the dev server.
- Both my local machine and server are running python 2.7.6 and django 1.7.3

I am able to access stuff located in my `/resources` directory, so I know apache can recognize some part of this.

I've been banging my head on this for hours, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It most likely doesn't hit your wsgi.py script at all. You can test this by adding a debug line printing something to a /tmp/test.txt file in your WSGI script. Then the next step is to maximize Apache log level and see what you get in Apache logs if the script is not run at all. Then the next step is to do a clean working configuration file from the known working example and start adding in bits until it stops working and you know what caused the issue.

Comment: As you can see Apache + mod_wsgi is not very friendly environment to debug and this is one reason why developers are migrating towards other solutions (hint: Nginx + uwsgi).

Comment: Well I did that, and it is hitting the script when i request a page. Though the script was unable to create a file in it's own directory because of file premissions. perhaps that has something to do with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After about 14 hours of Google-fu and a lot of failures, I finally found the solution. Apparently they made undocumented breaking changes in both Django 1.7 and Apache 2.4.

First, I needed to disable `mod_python` from Apache. Apparently it causes *silent* problems when WSGI is also enabled. As soon as I disabled it, my logs started blowing up, thank god. Here is the link I found where this solution was described to me: http://marc-abramowitz.com/archives/2012/09/28/some-tips-for-setting-up-apache-and-mod_wsgi/

Given the errors found from disabling `mod_python`, I discovered that Django's WSGI.py file needs to be initialized in this manner, differing to what is described in the docs:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/1629/#id_post_11030

Hope this helps poor souls who encounter this issue in the future.

Comment: Very good answer! Let's hope the future generations find this :)

Answer (score 2):

please have a look these steps :
create new file :

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/domain_name
```

write these lines into your new file.

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
        ServerAdmin yogesh@cisinlabs.com
        ServerName myurl.com
        ServerAlias myurl.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/docs/DocsEngine/wsgi.py

        Alias /static/ /home/cis/DjangoLive/cismailer/static/
        <Location "/static/">
            Options -Indexes
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then run:

```
sudo a2ensite domain_name
```

Then Open file :

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

change port in this file :

```
NameVirtualHost *:8000
Listen 8000
```

Then `sudo service apache2 restart`

Hope this will work for you.

if you using virtualenv your wsgi script file look like this:

```
import os
import sys
import site

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with

site.addsitedir('/path/of/your/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/var/www/docs/DocsEngine')
sys.path.append('/var/www/docs/DocsEngine/DocsEngine')


# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("/path/of/your/env/bin/activate_this.py")

execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "DocsEngine.settings")


import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Here is some like you can use for more info:
http://thecodeship.com/deployment/deploy-django-apache-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-django-with-mod_wsgi-and-apache-with-a-virtualenv-python-environment-on-a-debian-vps